# How to reference UIView which is inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a uiview in one of my table view cells. I would like to know if referencing it like this (it works 100%) is correct. If not, please tell me the proper way to do it.

Basically, all I am doing now is assigning the uiview to an instance variable inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Something like this:

```
myViewReference = cell.myView;
```

After that, changing properties of my ivar changes the properties of the uiview inside the cell as well, so it works perfectly.

Is this a good way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your `UITableView` is set

- If it is Dynamic Prototypes, it is not good practice to strongly
  reference it as `UITableViewCell`s are reusable as you scroll. A better way for this would be using `viewWithTag` method to obtain your `myViewReference`.

For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *myViewReference = [cell viewWithTag:1000];
    // If you don't use storyboard and init myViewReference programmatically then do this:
    if (!myViewReference) {
        myViewReference = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        myViewReference.tag = 1000;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myViewReference];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Get your UITableViewCell by identifying its indexPath.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *myViewReference = [cell viewWithTag:1000];
    [myViewReference doSomething];

}
```

- If it is Static Cells, then it is totally fine to have a strong reference from it. You can drag and drop the `IBOutlet` of your `myViewReference` and obtain it by calling: `self.myViewReference`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you tell me why is it better to reference a view with viewWithTag?

Comment: Because then you don't have to hold a strong reference to it. If you assign it to instance variable then you hold a strong reference and you will have to dealloc otherwise it will cause memory leak (even under ARC). Also, if you have 100 rows and hence 100 cells, you are not going to create 100 instance variables for it.

Comment: No worries. Glad that it helps.